# objdump on android kernel

Tags: android, linux-kernel, executable, objdump

I have taken android linux kernel split it from the gzip header and decompressed it. However when I try to do an objdump from the android ndk to dump the file I am getting a  File format not recognized error.

Anyone know how get a symbol table from the binary image.

On my android device I can do the following to get a symbol table:
cat /proc/kallsyms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not unique to Android - it happens on most (all?) Linux systems. The bootable image of the Linux kernel (on which Android is based) is not a proper ELF binary:

```
# file /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38.7-desktop-1mnb2 
/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38.7-desktop-1mnb2: Linux kernel x86 boot executable bzImage, version 2.6.38.7-desktop-1mnb2 (thomas@celeste.mandriva.com) #1 SMP Sun, RO-rootFS, root_dev 0x902, swap_dev 0x3, Normal VGA
# nm /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38.7-desktop-1mnb2 
nm: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38.7-desktop-1mnb2: File format not recognized
```

The bootable image is created by wrapping the [`vmlinux` kernel ELF binary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vmlinux) in a compressed container and adding a set of boot and decompression utilities. If you need a kernel image for debugging. the `vmlinux` file is what you need - I don't know if/where it exists in the Android NDK though.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [nm](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_nm.htm).

```
$ nm path/to/someobj
```

Comment: `nm` and `objcopy` both use `libbfd` from `binutils` as their backend. The results would be the same...